# $\sigma$-finiteness of $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}^1,\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}^1,\mu)$ where $$\mu(A):=\mathcal{H}^0(A\cap\mathbb{Q}),\quad A\in\mathcal{B}^1,$$
where $\mathcal{H}^0$ is the counting measure. According to my course this measure space is $\sigma$-finite.

Reviewing this statement, I remembered the example of Vitali and considered $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ and some set of representatives $R$. Now it is $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} q+R$ and $(\mu(q+R)\leq 2,\ q\in\mathbb{Q})$, if only $q+R$ was in $\mathcal{B}^1$ for every $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. But this isn't the case, right?

So, is this measure space really $\sigma$-finite, or do we need to consider $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ as the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: To me, if $\mu$ would be $\sigma -$finite, then $\mathbb R$ would be countable. So I don't think it is... I would be curious to se the argument.

Comment: @idm I think, if we would define $\mu$ that way on every subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the argument in my question would hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The countable family of Borel sets
$$
\{s\},\qquad \text{where }s \in \mathbb Q
\\
\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q
$$
covers the space; and all of these have finite measure.  The sets $\{s\}$ have measure $1$, and the set $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ has measure $0$.